# why formatted strings do not need to have type conversion before including the variable or operation in the {curly brackets}?

Tags: python

as you know , python is a strongly typed language that does not allow concatenation of type `int` with `str`.

As you can see below; As I stated above python does not allow for such operations(concatenation of str with int due to the language's features).

```
a = 10
b = '20'
print(a + b)
#throws the error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'**
```

But Look into this too:

```
a = 1
b = '2'
print(f"{a} and {b}")
print("{} and {}".format(a, b))#or this for example
```

**Here I did not converted variable a which has an `int` type assigned to ; into string, but I can include it in the formatted string**

**My question is ... what happens under the curtains when python interpreter encounters with this expression `print(f"{a} and {b}")`**

Comment: It's not exlusively the f-string's thing. The old str.format() also cast str automatically to any input.

Comment: @OlegO; I am curious about how it does this ?

Comment: Formatting strings is different from using arithmetic operators.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude; could you explain more.

Comment: Python is strongly, dynamically typed!

Comment: @FredrikPihl; I know Dynamic: Types checked on the fly, during execution.

Comment: I don't claim to know how string formatting and `f` strings in Python actually works, but one possible way which seems reasonable is that it's a two-step process: First `f"{a} and {b}"` is simply translated to `"{} and {}".format(a, b)`; Then the `format` function traverses the formatting string, and when it sees a `{}` then it converts the corresponding argument into a string (if possible) and replaces `{}` with that string.

Comment: If you want to know how it really works Python is open-source, and all the source is available for anyone to read.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude; So you mean I CAN understand the WHY; Once I read the source code ?

Comment: well, everything in pythons is an object and they are stringified using the `__str__(self) ` method for object's class.

Comment: @m.rostami: Yes, if you know C and can find the relevant code in the Python source. The reason I don't find it particularly worth while to investigate is because f-strings are built in to Python's syntax. Asking how they work is like asking how the `def` or `return` keywords work.

Comment: @luther fstrings are just syntactic sugar over the `str.format()` function.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers hmm, I read that f-strings are actually faster. If it's just a syntactic sugar, this is not possible, right?

Comment: @OlegO why not ? If you save the python-level attribute resolution (costly) and method call (costly) and instead directly invoke the C-level implementation, you certainly save a few cpu cycles. When I say "syntactic sugar" it doesn't mean that the code would go thru a preprocessor to replace fstrings with str.format calls, just that the code doing the formatting part (at the runtime level) is actually the same so luther's comment is possibly slightly out. FWIW, the `def` statement is syntactic sugar too (you can build a function object directly by code without using this statement).

Comment: Even if f-strings are syntactic sugar, they're still a form of syntax that you can't replicate with stuff like dunder methods. It's not clear how deep an explanation the OP needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **what happens under the curtains when python interpreter encounters with this expression** `print(f"{a} and {b}")`

What happens is that before `a` and `b` are built into the string, `str(a)` and `str(b)` are called. You can see this yourself when you build 2 classes like this:

```
class Test1(object):
    pass

class Test2(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "surprise"
```

which do the same (nothing) but `Test2` returns `"surprise"` when `str(Test2())` is called.

When you want to convince yourself try this:

```
t1 = Test1()
t2 = Test2()

print(t1)
print(t2)

print(f"{t1}")
print(f"{t2}")

print("{}".format(t1))
print("{}".format(t2))
```

Each time the same two lines are printed.

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in [chapter 2 of Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

> If a conversion is specified, the result of evaluating the expression is converted before formatting. Conversion `'!s'` calls [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) on the result, `'!r'` calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr), and `'!a'` calls [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii).

If no conversion is specified, it immediately continues to the following step:

> The result is then formatted using the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) protocol. The format specifier is passed to the [`__format__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) method of the expression or conversion result. An empty string is passed when the format specifier is omitted. The formatted result is then included in the final value of the whole string.

The `__format__()` method then follows the [format specifier mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) syntax to determine the resulting string representation.

In your case the result is the same as calling `str()` on the variables, but this does not apply to all variables. Based on [@Marv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356234/9504155), here is a little demonstration to show the difference:

```py
class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return "surprise"

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        return "test"

t1 = Test()

print(t1)
print(str(t1))
print(f"{t1}")
print("{}".format(t1))
>>> surprise
>>> surprise
>>> test
>>> test
```